# Kalman Filter Interpolation

Tags: gps, filtering, interpolation, geospatial, kalman-filter

I'm building a system that receives a stream of live GPS coordinates, around every second or two. I would like to smooth out the visualisation of it so that the location doesn't jump too much when there is a less then accurate datapoint. I would also like to visualise the speed of the moving point, not just jump from one to another.

To do it I have implemented a Kalman filter that gets the coordinates and models speed and acceleration. This helps smooth out the curve but the output of a Kalman filter has the same rate of one data point per second. I thought I would be able to interpolate this by running the "predict" part of Kalman filter 60 times per second, while the update part would only be done when a new coordinate arrives.

[However, it turns out this results in a non continuous function and there is a visual jump after a new update comes in.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xsEN.png)

How can I solve this problem? Is there an algorithm that would output a continuous smooth path while feeding it coordinate points?

Comment: If your prediction model is a rigid body model, then running the prediction step does nothing but add noise to your estimate, which will then result in a huge jump when a measurement comes in.